# Building ARM for Win IoT Core gives "not supported" error

Tags: c++, arm, windows-10-iot-core

> error MSB8022: Building Desktop applications for the ARM platform is
>   not supported.

When changing my console application that runs on Windows 10 IoT Core x86 (for Minnowboard), but when I select ARM I get the "not supported" error.

Is there a project setting that needs adjusting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

```
<WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport>true</WindowsSDKDesktopARMSupport>
<WindowsSDKDesktopARM64Support>true</WindowsSDKDesktopARM64Support>
```

to the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` node in the .csproj project file.